# How to make sure new Airflow DAG deployment is not Paused

Tags: airflow

When we deploy Airflow DAG, the State of DAG is Paused.

Is it possible to un-Pause the DAG after deployment automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration parameter dags_are_paused_at_creation should be set as False in the configuration file. The corresponding documentation link is below.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dags-are-paused-at-creation